# SQL Server : autoincrement for column, partitioned by values in another column

Tags: sql-server, row-number

Anyone have a solution for the following please? (the code snippets in both cases should be run as full blocks)

The following code simulates the situation for a daily processing job.

Here's day 1

```
Declare @poitem_source table (PONum int, txt varchar(50), status varchar(25)) 
Declare @poitem_destination table (PONum int, LineNum int, txt varchar(50)) 

insert @poitem_source 
values (1,'Item1', 'NEW'), (1,'Item2', 'NEW'), 
       (1,'Item3', 'NEW'), (2,'Item1', 'NEW'), 
       (2,'Item2', 'NEW')

update @poitem_source 
set status = 'PROCESSING' 
where status = 'NEW'

insert @poitem_destination 
   SELECT 
      PONum, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PONum ORDER BY PONum) AS POLineNumber, 
      txt 
   FROM 
      @poitem_source 
   WHERE 
      status = 'PROCESSING'

update @poitem_source 
set status = 'DONE' 
where status = 'PROCESSING'

select * 
from @poitem_destination 
order by PONum, txt
```

If you run it, you will see that LineNum increments 1...n for each PONum in the destination table.

However, this clearly will not work for day 2... here's the code...

```
Declare @poitem_source table (PONum int, txt varchar(50), status varchar(25)) 
Declare @poitem_destination table (PONum int, LineNum int, txt varchar(50)) 

insert @poitem_source 
values (1,'Item1', 'NEW'), (1,'Item2', 'NEW'), (1,'Item3', 'NEW'), 
       (2,'Item1', 'NEW'), (2,'Item2', 'NEW')

update @poitem_source 
set status = 'PROCESSING' 
where status = 'NEW'

insert @poitem_destination 
   select
      PONum, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PONum ORDER BY PONum) AS POLineNumber, 
      txt 
   from 
      @poitem_source 
   where 
      status = 'PROCESSING'

update @poitem_source 
set status = 'DONE' 
where status = 'PROCESSING'

select * 
from @poitem_destination 
order by PONum, txt

--- 2nd day

insert @poitem_source 
values (1,'Item4', 'NEW'), (2,'Item3', 'NEW')

update @poitem_source 
set status = 'PROCESSING' 
where status = 'NEW'

insert @poitem_destination 
   select
      PONum, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PONum ORDER BY PONum) AS POLineNumber, 
      txt 
   from @poitem_source 
   where status = 'PROCESSING'

update @poitem_source 
set status = 'DONE' 
where status = 'PROCESSING'

select * 
from @poitem_destination 
order by PONum, txt
```

For day 2, the additional items get line numbers of 1, because the select query is not linked in any way to the destination table (and I don't believe it can be).

Anyone have an alternative solution for generating these line numbers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution as follows

```
Declare @poitem_source table (PONum int, txt varchar(50), status varchar(25)) 
Declare @poitem_destination table (PONum int, LineNum int, txt varchar(50)) 


insert @poitem_source values (1,'Item1', 'NEW'), (1,'Item2', 'NEW'), (1,'Item3', 'NEW'), (2,'Item1', 'NEW'), (2,'Item2', 'NEW')

update @poitem_source set status = 'PROCESSING' where status = 'NEW'

insert @poitem_destination 
SELECT PONum, ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(PARTITION BY PONum ORDER BY PONum) + (select isnull(max(linenum),0) from @poitem_destination d where d.PONum = s.PONum)  AS POLineNumber, txt from @poitem_source s where status = 'PROCESSING'

select * from @poitem_destination order by PONum, txt

update @poitem_source set status = 'DONE' where status = 'PROCESSING'

--- 2nd day

insert @poitem_source values (1,'Item4', 'NEW'), (2,'Item3', 'NEW')

update @poitem_source set status = 'PROCESSING' where status = 'NEW'

insert @poitem_destination 
SELECT PONum, ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(PARTITION BY PONum ORDER BY PONum) + (select isnull(max(linenum),0) from @poitem_destination d where d.PONum = s.PONum)  AS POLineNumber, txt from @poitem_source s where status = 'PROCESSING'

update @poitem_source set status = 'DONE' where status = 'PROCESSING'

select * from @poitem_destination order by PONum, txt
```

So now we can use PONum & LineNum as the primary key

Answer (score 0):

Add an IDENTITY column to your table (and this would be a good candidate for a primary key for the table).  That will give it a unique incremented line number within the table.  You could then maintain your daily line numbers.

Like this:

```
Declare @poitem_source table (ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, PONum int, txt varchar(50), status varchar(25))
```

Alternatively, you could just have your line number column be an `IDENTITY(1,1)`; however, this will lose data and probably cause you problems down the road ("I need LineNumber X from day Y ..." would now be more difficult to get).

Comment: IDENTITY is *not* a primary key. It's simply an attribute of the column. You can even have multiple identity columns in the same table

Comment: Yes, I'm recommending he do both IDENTITY and make that the primary key.  Edited to clarify.

Comment: Identity doesn't work - I need the value to increment for the PONum - however, I have the solution - correlated sub-query - added to question - thanks for suggestions though